# Get/set id of a filter field in ag-grid for Angular 2

Tags: angular, filter, ag-grid

I am making a table in angular2 using ag-grid.

i have several columns and it is possible to filter on each column.
(I use custom filter) 
For further development of my application i need an id of the filter field.

My rows are like this:

```
    createColumnDefs()  {
    this.columnDefs =[
        { headerName: "ID", field: "id", width:80, filterFramework:{

            component: PartialMatchFilterComponent,
            moduleImports: [FormsModule]
        }},
        { headerName: "Extern id", field: "externalRefId", width:150, filterFramework:{

            component: PartialMatchFilterComponent,
            moduleImports: [FormsModule]
        }},
        { headerName: "Name", field: "customerLastName", width:80,filterFramework:{

            component: PartialMatchFilterComponent,
            moduleImports: [FormsModule]
        }}
    ]
}
```

For example the user select the *Name* field to filter. I want to know that the user selected *Name* field. How can i check which filter field the user has chosen (for example: show in the console.log() )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide extra data to your components by supplying params - for example, with a filter you can use filterParams:

```
filterFramework: {
    component: PartialMatchFilterComponent,
    moduleImports: [FormsModule]
},
filterParams: {
    field: "name"
},
```

Then in the agInit method you'll be able to pull this information off for later use:

```
agInit(params:IFilterParams):void {
    console.log(params.field);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. This works. I added **colId** in the rows like this:

`{ headerName: "Straat", colId: 'workorder.location.street', field: "workorderStreet", width:100, filterFramework:{

               component: PartialMatchFilterComponent,
                moduleImports: [FormsModule]
            }}` 

And i used it like this: 

`this.params.colDef.colId` in the *agInit* function

Comment: good to hear :-)  - please note that with 7.x there are many breaking changes around ng2 usage - take a look at the docs for more information: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-2-beta-release/